# Transposing Column Values to Row With Merged Cells in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There is a [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JxWF3yG4Rzj-I_BWOWBqMxRXHLXBvHyoYB1jgYhQDIE/edit#gid=0) in which the data is presented as in three rows, `A1:BK3`. My task is to switch this data from going across the columns, to down rows, as shown in cells `A10:C41`

I was able to implement only the data output for the DAY, but I do not know how to output the data for the NIGHT.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to adjust the column by one to the right. This seemed to work...

```
=INDEX($B$1:$BK$3; MATCH($A$3; $A$1:$A$3; 0); MATCH($A11; $B$2:$BK$2; 0)+1)
```